# Why is jQuery not working in IE and Edge?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a button that toggles classes using jQuery and it saves the states to keep its class after refresh but, anyway. I tried this on IE and Edge and everything but the button works just fine. Is this an issue with the code below or IE and Edge that I will need to use Vanilla JS to fix?
*Note: I am using jQuery 2.2.4 min if that helps any*

```
//Stores the active and inactive classes appended to the toggle switch
  function toggleHandle() {
    $('.handle').toggleClass('slide');
  }

  if (sessionStorage.getItem('switch-state') && sessionStorage.getItem('switch-state') === "true") {
    $('.toggle-theme-cont').addClass('color-swap');
    toggleHandle();
  }

  $('.toggle-theme-cont').click(function() {
    let el = $('.toggle-theme-cont');
    toggleHandle();
    el.toggleClass('color-swap');
    sessionStorage.setItem('switch-state', el.hasClass('color-swap'));
  });
 });
```

Thanks in advance!

*Update: I tried jQuery 3.3.1 and now it is pulling an internal error within jQuery itself at (2,30140)*

Comment: Do you see any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: there seems to be an extra `});` in the code you posted - perhaps that's significant - perhaps it isn't

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes, I looked at it and line 13 says an error but is undefined so it isn't much help seeing as I know something is wrong just not what it is.

Comment: @JaromandaX That is the close of the first line with $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: fair enough @JordanDunton - at least we know that the elements are more likely to exist - what is the error you are getting (which line is line 13, clearly you haven't posted enough for us to know which line is line 13)

Comment: @JaromandaX It is the line where the if statment startes and all the Edge console says is "Undefined Error"

Comment: sessionStorage only exists in IE8 or newer - is your IE in "legacy mode" perhaps?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208380/discussion-between-jordan-dunton-and-jaromanda-x).